# Comparison operator in PySpark (not equal/ !=)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, null, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to obtain all rows in a dataframe where two flags are set to '1' and subsequently all those that where only one of two is set to '1' and the other **NOT EQUAL** to '1'

With the following schema (three columns),

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a',1,'null'),('b',1,1),('c',1,'null'),('d','null',1),('e',1,1)], #,('f',1,'NaN'),('g','bla',1)],
                            schema=('id', 'foo', 'bar')
                            )
```

I obtain the following dataframe:

```
+---+----+----+
| id| foo| bar|
+---+----+----+
|  a|   1|null|
|  b|   1|   1|
|  c|   1|null|
|  d|null|   1|
|  e|   1|   1|
+---+----+----+
```

When I apply the desired filters, the first filter (foo=1 AND bar=1) works, but not the other (foo=1 AND NOT bar=1)

```
foobar_df = df.filter( (df.foo==1) & (df.bar==1) )
```

yields:

```
+---+---+---+
| id|foo|bar|
+---+---+---+
|  b|  1|  1|
|  e|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

**Here is the non-behaving filter:**

```
foo_df = df.filter( (df.foo==1) & (df.bar!=1) )
foo_df.show()
+---+---+---+
| id|foo|bar|
+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+
```

Why is it not filtering? How can I get the columns where only foo is equal to '1'?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To filter null values try:

`foo_df = df.filter( (df.foo==1) & (df.bar.isNull()) )`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isNull

Comment: This entry does not answer the question, which referred to the use of the "!=" operator in pyspark.

Answer (score 30):

> Why is it not filtering

Because it is SQL and `NULL` indicates missing values. Because of that any comparison to `NULL`, other than `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` is undefined. You need either:

```
col("bar").isNull() | (col("bar") != 1)
```

or

```
coalesce(col("bar") != 1, lit(True))
```

or ([PySpark >= 2.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20290)):

```
col("bar").eqNullSafe(1)
```

if you want null safe comparisons in PySpark.

Also `'null'` is not a valid way to introduce `NULL` literal. You should use `None` to indicate missing objects.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, coalesce, lit

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('a', 1, 1), ('a',1, None), ('b', 1, 1),
    ('c' ,1, None), ('d', None, 1),('e', 1, 1)
]).toDF('id', 'foo', 'bar')

df.where((col("foo") == 1) & (col("bar").isNull() | (col("bar") != 1))).show()

## +---+---+----+
## | id|foo| bar|
## +---+---+----+
## |  a|  1|null|
## |  c|  1|null|
## +---+---+----+

df.where((col("foo") == 1) & coalesce(col("bar") != 1, lit(True))).show()

## +---+---+----+
## | id|foo| bar|
## +---+---+----+
## |  a|  1|null|
## |  c|  1|null|
## +---+---+----+
```

Comment: isNull() is very useful

Comment: This is wrong for pyspark.  There is no "!=" operator in that language.  The correct answer is posted below (using the "==" operator with the "~" negator.

Answer (score 0):

The selected correct answer does not address the question, and the other answers are all wrong for pyspark.

There is no "!=" operator equivalent in pyspark for this solution.  The correct answer is to use "==" and the "~" negation operator, like this:

```
df = df.withColumn(when(~(col("column_name_here") == "string_value")), lit("update_value").cast(SomeType()))
```