# Get IDs for duplicate rows (considering all other columns) in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark sql dataframe, consisting of an `ID` column and `n` "data" columns, i.e.

```
id | dat1 | dat2 | ... | datn
```

The `id` columnn is uniquely determined, whereas, looking at `dat1 ... datn` there may be duplicates.

My goal is to find the `id`s of those duplicates.

My approach so far:

- get the duplicate rows using `groupBy`:

  `dup_df = df.groupBy(df.columns[1:]).count().filter('count > 1')`
- join the `dup_df` with the entire `df` to get the duplicate rows **including** `id`:

  `df.join(dup_df, df.columns[1:])`

I am quite certain that this is basically correct, it fails because the `dat1 ... datn` columns contain `null` values.

To do the `join` on `null` values, I found .e.g [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120934/comparison-operator-in-pyspark-not-equal). But this would require to construct a huge "string join condition".

Thus my questions:

1. Is there a simple / more generic / more pythonic way to do `joins` on `null` values?
2. Or, even better, is there another (easier, more beautiful, ...) method to get the desired `id`s?

BTW: I am using Spark 2.1.0 and Python 3.5.3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If number `ids` per group is relatively small you can `groupBy` and `collect_list`. Required imports

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, size
```

example data:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, "a", "b", 3),
    (2, None, "f", None),
    (3, "g", "h", 4),
    (4, None, "f", None),
    (5, "a", "b", 3)
]).toDF(["id"])
```

query:

```
(df
   .groupBy(df.columns[1:])
   .agg(collect_list("id").alias("ids"))
   .where(size("ids") > 1))
```

and the result:

```
+----+---+----+------+
|  _2| _3|  _4|   ids|
+----+---+----+------+
|null|  f|null|[2, 4]|
|   a|  b|   3|[1, 5]|
+----+---+----+------+
```

You can apply `explode` twice (or use an `udf`) to an output equivalent to the one returned from `join`.

You can also identify groups using minimal `id` per group. A few additional imports:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, min
```

window definition:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy(df.columns[1:])
```

query:

```py
(df
    .select(
        "*", 
        count("*").over(w).alias("_cnt"), 
        min("id").over(w).alias("group"))
    .where(col("_cnt") > 1))
```

and the result:

```
+---+----+---+----+----+-----+
| id|  _2| _3|  _4|_cnt|group|
+---+----+---+----+----+-----+
|  2|null|  f|null|   2|    2|
|  4|null|  f|null|   2|    2|
|  1|   a|  b|   3|   2|    1|
|  5|   a|  b|   3|   2|    1|
+---+----+---+----+----+-----+
```

You can further use `group` column for self join.