# How to fix "Cannot use null as map key!" error in Spark.SQL with Python 3 using Group_Map

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, hadoop

I am working with Spark.SQL and I am trying to make a pivot table with the MAP statement, in order to have the values of one column as different columns.

I prepared a first table with this query:

```
spark.sql("""CREATE TABLE TABLE_01 STORED AS PARQUET AS
select
ROWS,
COLUMNS,
count(*) as NUM_ROWS
from TABLE_00
group by ROWS, COLUMNS
order by ROWS, COLUMNS
""")
```

The idea is convert this:

```
ROWS    COLUMNS NUM_ROWS
VALUE1   COL2    2
VALUE1   COL3    50
VALUE2   COL1    20
VALUE2   COL2    1
VALUE2   COL3    30
```

Into this:

```
                COLUMNS

              COL1          |  COL2     |  COL3
ROWS
      ------------------------------------------------------
VALUE1  0 (The problem)     |    2      |   50

VALUE2       20             |    1      |   30
```

I had a query in Python2 which used to work, but now I have to change to Python3 and I going crazy. The query is:

```
spark.sql("""CREATE TABLE TABLE_02 STORED AS PARQUET AS
select
a.ROWS,
coalesce(sum(a.group_map['COL1']),0) as COL1,
coalesce(sum(a.group_map['COL2']),0) as COL2,
coalesce(sum(a.group_map['COL3']),0) as COL3
from 
    (
    select ROWS, map(COLUMNS,NUM_ROWS) as group_map
    from TABLE_01
    ) a
group by a.ROWS
""")
```

The output is: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use null as map key!

Any help? Why did it work with Python2?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39121638/4777984

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define a missing value, in this case, VALUE1, COL1. An empty value is not a proper way to return a `Null` value, you'll need to define it as `None`. So what you shall do is define VALUE1, COL1 as `None`.

Comment: Could you give me more detail?

Comment: Now I see your error. Forget about `dict`, I'll edit my answer. In SQL, you need to define a 'none' value, not just put a missing object, in your case: VALUE 1, COL1. You'll need to define it as none.

Comment: How? I need to give that None value as default to all values because it has to be prepared to find null anywhere. Do you know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: They will return null values if they find it, but you need to define something to VALUE 1, COL1 as it understand as an empty value.

Comment: As you can see, the original table does not contain all the possible combinations between COLS and ROWS. I cannot convert the missing combinations to something. I simply do not have rows with the value COL1, VALUE1. How can I map that value?

Comment: @AlejandroAbad Look at this post. It might help you more than I.  stackoverflow.com/a/39121638/4777984 .

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you are looking at pivoting the data, rather than manually writing the code for that, you can try below block of code

```
df
  .groupBy($"<column name>", .. <columns to be grouped, here VALUE1, VALUE2,...>)
  .pivot("<column name>",...<columns to pivot, here COL1, COL2, ...>)
  .agg(<aggreagation expressions..>)
```