# Filtering parquet row is not work properly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, impala

I want to read a parquet file and filter a column by specifying a condition, but it doesn't work.

I don't understand why the number of rows would not be the expected value if I add 'NOT'.

Example:

pyspark: where

```
$ df = spark.read.parquet("s3://test/parquet/date=2023-01-31")
$ df.count()
175371
$ df.where("test_column = 'test_column_test'").count()
1
$ df.where("NOT test_column = 'test_column_test'").count()
175362  # expected: 175370
```

pyspark: filter

```
$ df = spark.read.parquet("s3://test/parquet/date=2023-01-31")
$ df.count()
175371
$ df.filter(df["test_column"]=="test_column_test").count()
1
$ df.filter(df["test_column"]!="test_column_test").count()
175362  # expected: 175370
```

impala

```
$ SELECT count(*) FROM test.test_table WHERE date='2023-01-31';
175371
$ SELECT count(*) FROM test.test_table WHERE date='2023-01-31' AND test_column = 'test_column_test';
1
$ SELECT count(*) FROM test.test_table WHERE date='2023-01-31' AND NOT test_column = 'test_column_test';
175362  # expected: 175370
```

I would like to know how to resolve it.

Comment: Can you do a null count on that column?

Comment: Hi @RehanRajput
  $ SELECT count(*) FROM test.test_table WHERE date='2023-01-31' AND test_column  
is NULL;
  8
  Thanks! It appears that null was not included in the results.  How can I include null in the count in spark?

Comment: You can look at the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39121638/16726018) for more details. `df.where(coalesce(col("test_column") != "test_column_test", lit(True))` should work in case you want to include nulls in your inequality check.

Comment: Also, another helpful resource is the [null semantics documentation in pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-null-semantics.html)